# Headless ssh-access to Ubuntu in RPI4

Tags: networking, server, ssh, raspberrypi

I've run the rpi imager to burn the image into an SD card, and configured netplan to connect to wifi on start up.

Checked using `arp -a` and the address never showed, but I accessed the router and the rpi is there.

After trying to ssh it, `arp -a` shows the address (any thoughts?).

But the problem is, it says 'connection refused'. Exact log:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.19 port 22: Connection refused
```

How can I edit the files so that it either starts the ssh service automatically at startup (I can't tell if it is running or not atm), or to know how to access it.

I don't have a monitor around.

Comment: Is this the Ubuntu "Core" version? If so, did you upload the public key to the Ubuntu server as it says in [the tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-core-on-raspberry-pi#1-overview)?

Comment: @user68186 I don't know what is the diff bw ubuntu server and core, but it is the standalone server

Comment: ARP cache is populated only when a paket was sent to or received from target.

Comment: @Virsacer awesome, thanks for that. So I should ping all devices in the lan first?

Comment: You may need to install `openssh-server`. Please edit the question and indicate if it is installed and if you did any configuration of the sshd server.

Comment: I didn't access the raspberry for the simple reason that I am running it headless (no monitor). It runs an ubuntu 20.04 server so I presume `ssh` is installed, I could take a look at the burned image. @user68186

Comment: Please update the question once you check. Also make sure whether you have installed the standard server or the "Core" version, as ssh works slightly differently in server and Core.

Comment: @Minsky I dont see a reason, why you would need all mac adresses pre-cached, but if you want that, pinging does the trick

Comment: How do you get another lan device's ip otherwise? @Virsacer

Comment: @user68186 ubuntu 20.04 server and it has ssh installed but not sure how to check if it is enabled

Comment: @Minsky How do you get the IP to ping it in the first place?

Comment: I would ping the with a broadcast destination IP @Virsacer

Comment: @Minsky You should look up the IP with DNS or in the DHCP-server. `nmap` can also be used to check which IPs are "alive"